# Error Código KQL

Tags: azure

tengo éste código y me da un error que no consigo depurar. ¿Me ayudáis?

```
customEvents
| where name == 'la_webapp_load' or name == 'la_fetch_jwt' or name =='la_fetch_aura_id'
| order by session_Id, timestamp asc
| serialize nextEvent = next(name, 1 ), nextDimensions =next(customDimensions, 1 ), furtherEvent = next(name, 2 )
| make-series JwtWasValid = sumif( 1 , name == 'la_webapp_load' and nextEvent == 'la_fetch_aura_id' and nextDimensions[ 'status' ] ==
'success' ), JwtFromStart = sumif( 1 , name == 'la_webapp_load' and nextEvent == 'la_fetch_jwt' ), JwtWasInvalid = sumif( 1 , name ==
'la_webapp_load' and nextEvent == 'la_fetch_aura_id' and nextDimensions[ 'status' ] == 'error' and furtherEvent == 'la_fetch_jwt' ) on timestamp step {timeStep}
| render areachart
```

el error

```
Query could not be parsed at '{' on line [7,150]

Token: {
Line: 7
Position: 150
Si el problema persiste, abra un vale de soporte. Request id: 21192b79-129a-4143-b154-72d3403501ea
```

Comment: Hola! Por qué usas llaves `{ timeStep }`. No veo su uso en ninguna parte de la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kql-quick-reference)

Comment: Las llaves es para meter valores en un campo de filtro en el libro de Azure, pero se puede quitar y dejarlo así        on timestamp